# "Override" parameter of function in js

Tags: javascript

Assuming that I have something like this :

```js
const hsl = (hue: number, saturation: number, lightness: number) => {
   return `hsl(
      ${hue}, 
      ${saturation},
      ${lightness}
      )`;
};
```

```js
const colors = {
   home: hsl(250, 50, 50);
};
```

is it possible to create a function to override any parameter ? for example:

```js
setNewHue(40, colors.home)
```

Comment: assign ?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: not clear what you are asking for.  but hsl returns a string, thus the variable hue is no longer available.  you should create a new object type that stores its own hue, saturation, lightness and implements a toString that returns the hsl string you want

Comment: yes I already create a new object with new value. I was just curious I can do something like this. but yeah it gives sense now